# title of dhtmlxTabbar tab

Tags: tabbar, dhtmlx

How can I access in 4+ version of dhtmlxTabbar  to the title property (tooltip) of a tab. I used to do it in version 3.6 as:

```
tabbar._tabs[nameTab].title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
tabbar.t[tabID].tab.title
```